# Does the Lich have a maximum max HP?

Tags: rogue-legacy

As the lich, you gain maximum HP whenever you kill an enemy. Does this go up indefinitely as long as you keep killing enemies, or is there some cap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so I cleared out about 90% of the castle with a lich and here are some numbers:

I started with:

- **Hp** = 135
- **Mp** = 167

I reached the cap on Hp (which I guess answers this question but I wanted to figure out some more):

- **Hp** = 383
- **Mp** = 167

I used HP Conversion (popped up -191 max hp, +191 max mp):

- **Hp** = 191
- **Mp** = 358

I used HP Conversion again (popped up -99 max hp, +99 max mp):

- **Hp** = 100
- **Mp** = 457

(Found a +5 hp stat in a chest here)

I reached the cap on Hp once again:

- **Hp** = 386 (383 + 5/2?)
- **Mp** = 457

I used HP Conversion again (popped up -194 max hp, + 194 max mp):

- **Hp** = 194
- **Mp** = 651

I used HP Conversion again (popped up Max MP Converted. Need higher level)

So then I just got to the HP cap again and here is my final result:

[image: Maxed out Lich]
 My stats read 386 Max HP and 651 Max MP

So the max cap for both stats are determined by your overall stat in that, the biggest thing that stood out to me was the max hp + 5 stat increased my HP cap by 3 (maybe 2.5?).

I may try to see what Max Hp paladins and barbarians have with out upgrading and keeping track of stat upgrades I find. Maybe i'll take off Hp giving equipment and subtract the bonuses my lich has on right now to see how he matches up, could do the same for Archmages or something as well.

But first this guy has to die, or maybe beat my last 2 + final bosses.

**Edit**: Ponce too strong for the crowstorm lich :( but back too numbers:

Didn't purchase any HP+ or MP+ with my money, didn't get any stats so just dis-equipped.

Hp w/o equip bonuses:

- **Lich** HP Cap = 311
- **Barbarian** Max HP = 473
- **Paladin** Max HP = 315

Most I could say here is the cap is about the same as the Paladin's current Max HP

Mp w/o equip bonuses:

- **Lich** MP Cap = 566
- **Archmage** Max MP = 375

So the Lich caps at about 1.5 times as much MP as the Archmage currently has max.

Comment: i guess the MAX HP are working like this: HP Cap = 100% (= Paladin HP) But it will not cap there, it will check before each monster slain : Current HP + 4HP >= HP Cap ? Most likely there are some rounding errors so your actual Hp are something like 311.3 and 311.3+4 > 315, so it wont increase any more.

Comment: one thing i noticed, is that if i start off with a lower hp (by equipping armour which decreases start hp) then i max out at a smaller number than if i started with a higher HP. Perhaps the calculation is percentage based on its start value, which happens to coincide with the difference between lich and paladin?

Comment: The +5HP only gave your Lich +3HP because Lich's have 35% starting HP. Same thing with barbarians, they would get a +7/8HP boost because they get a 150% bonus to maxHP. So +5HP only really gives +5 to paladins.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a maximum.  It's equal to `StartingHP * 20/7` *(rounded up)*.

Due to the way it's coded, if a kill puts you over the max HP, you won't gain *any* HP.  Since you gain a fixed 4 HP per kill, your max could be up to 3 less than this.  Additionally, the author does some weird stuff with rounding, so the max-HP *could*, in rare instances, go +/- 1 more from that.

---

**Source:**  I took a look at the source code *(it's in `RogueCastle.EnemyObj.Kill()` and `RogueCastle.PlayerObj.MaxHealth`)*