# Is there an overall stat cap?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Is there an overall stat cap AND is there a hard cap on single stats such as strength or intelligence?  Or can I just keep gaining permanent stat upgrades from fairy chests?

Comment: A comment ***[here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/241600/discussions/0/846958223130756711/?l=swedish)*** mentions chest farming to get infinite stats. Not conclusive, though.

Comment: I have found the Max HP to be equal to StartingHP * 20/7 (rounded up).

Due to the way it's coded, if a kill puts you over the max HP, you won't gain any HP. Since you gain a fixed 4 HP per kill, your max could be up to 3 less than this. Additionally, the author does some weird stuff with rounding, so the max-HP could, in rare instances, go +/- 1 more from that. Source: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122208/does-the-lich-have-a-maximum-max-hp

Comment: @Timtech That's only for the Lich King/Queen's ability though. He's asking about the permanent stat boosts that carry across all future generations.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Okay, thanks for clarifying. Still, it remains to be a partial answer, and it's probably the best that anyone will find without a bounty placed.

Answer (score 7):

There are no caps as far as I know.

In fact, the only way to progress further in NG+ mode once you have purchased all the upgrades is by farming fairy chests for stat boosts. The fairy chest stat boosts are not counted towards the castle upgrades.

Source: Beating the game on NG+5 and beyond

Comment: To be noted, even Farming chests and all won't be enough to be new game 10+, you can not build up stats fast enough to follow exponential ennemy power. I'm now at NG 15+ and i'm forced to trick with assassins or stopping time wizards, then rush the doors and be very focused on bosses to get them, it's quite hard, but the time needed tu build up stats becomes too long and there is evntually no reason to look for any stats cap, Your stats are not important anymore from NG 5+ .

Answer (score -2):

There is a theoretical stat cap based on what kind of variable the code uses.  But, in most cases, there is just no way you're going to hit that cap.  And, if the programmer didn't account for anyone actually reaching this maximum, funny things will happen if you hit it (typically the variable cycling around to a negative value, or resetting back to 0, but it could also completely hose the game).

If the program is set up to use just normal integers for everything without trying to streamline with variables specifically targeted to likely data size(which is a fairly reasonable assumption), the theoretical maximum for any stat will be 2,147,483,647.

To put that in perspective, to get 2,147,483,647 points in attack, you'll need to collect one billion attack chests.  Assuming you can speed through with mobility runes to a point where you're collecting +2 to attack every 5 minutes, that would still take you two billion hours to accomplish, which is on the order of two hundred thousand years.

Armor a tad different.  You reach the practical maximum for armor at around 19,800 points of armor (at which point the damage taken goes under 1%).  This would be doable, but you'd probably get really bored of the grinding far before you hit it.  Specifically, you'd need to collect 9,725 chests to get there.  If you somehow managed to average a +2 armor increase every 10 minutes, it would still take you 1,620 hours to accomplish this feat.  Once you did it, though, you would be essentially invulnerable or close enough, anyway.