# Does the lich’s “+max HP” ability counter blood items’ “­−HP”?

Tags: rogue-legacy

If you have the blood (or any item) with “−HP”, will your lich’s ability to gain max HP eventually get you to 100% regardless of the penalty from the items? Or is it 100% minus item penalty at most?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122208/does-the-lich-have-a-maximum-max-hp.  It seems to be a percentage of what your starting HP is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -hp from items decreases the maximum health attainable on a Lich.